# BOKEH FLASK : Flask cant display large array resulted by heavy computing script into bokeh, but worked in light script with the same size of array

Tags: flask, bokeh

im developing web application using flask and use bokeh to visualize the result. It read tiff file as array then process it with some mathematical computation and then map the result into colormap and display it with bokeh, the array has size of 7771x7631. When i try to use only 1/8 of the total script which also resulted in array of 7771x7631, it works fine. But then when i try to use the whole script which is quite heavy and need two minutes to run completely and also resulted in array of 7771x7631, the browser didnt display any plot with bokeh. The script is fine and works as it should be, because when i try to slice the resulted array into half size (4000x4000) it worked. I really dont know why this could happen. Please help me.

Answer (score 0):

This is not a reasonable size for image plots in Bokeh. It is well outside the intended/expected usage size for such (not even close, really). I can imagine a variety of reasons it might not work on any given browser, starting with browser-specific memory or canvas size limitations, browser bugs, etc. An RGBA array of that size is alone nearly a quarter of a gigabyte, it has to be received as a base64-encoded string (which is slightly larger) which is then converted into JS typed arrays. Both of those have to exist simultaneously, at least long enough to decode things, which means the browser stack must accommodate more than half a gigabyte on the stack at once [1]. Many browsers will simply won't. There is nothing at all that the project can do about this.

If you have data of this size you really must look in to some kind of downsampling approach that get the images that are sent to the browser down to more manageable size that also more closely match the pixel dimensions of the actual plot canvas. If you send such huge images to a smaller canvas then the browser will end up subsampling regardless, just to fit things on the canvas. The only difference is that you have no control over the process in that case. So better to take an active role in how things the downsampling is accomplished. A tool like [Datashader](https://datashader.org/), which works well with Bokeh, might be useful.

[1] If this was a Bokeh server application, then the data could be sent in a raw binary format directly into typed array buffers, which would avoid roughly half that cost. It might help some, but I would still consider this usage very extreme.

Comment: Hi, thanks for the answer. But the odd thing is, its actually work when i use simple script. I can plot that large array to bokeh, eventhough its not a smooth task just like what you state. If i could explain it simply, its like i have 7771x7631 array called 'arr', the simple script is like result=arr*5, then i plot the result array to bokeh, it works, but when i change the script to result = (arr*5)+(arr**2)+(arr/6)+(arr-9)+(arr*100), then i plot the result array to bokeh thats when it didnt work, of course the script is far more complex, i just want to give you the idea

Comment: I mean if using the simple script also make bokeh cant plot it, then it will make sense to me, well the problem is in bokeh then, but its not, it work on simple script. I swear the array has the same size, and also im not making any change on the flask file, its call the same function from imported python script, i only change the script on the processing function